# How to modify or change a particular object from JSON array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Suppose I have a JSON array like:

```
[{
    "box": "box1",    
    "parent": [{
        "id": "box0"
    }],
    "child": [{
        "id": "box2"
    }]
},{
    "box": "box2",
    "parent": [{
        "id": "box1"
    }],
    "child": [{
        "id": "box3"
    },{
        "id": "box4"
    }]
}]
```

Now assume that I want to change a value `parent` `id` of `box2` then how do I do that.

How can I specifically change a particular value?

Comment: What about deserializing this JSON string to an object, change the value in the object and then serializing this object ?

Comment: Any example would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = [{
  'box': 'box1',
  'parent': [{
    'id': 'box0'
  }],
  'child': [{
    'id': 'box2'
  }]
}, {
  'box': 'box2',
  'parent': [{
    'id': 'box1'
  }],
  'child': [{
    'id': 'box3'
  }, {
    'id': 'box4'
  }]
}];

arr = arr.map(function(box) {
   if (box.box === 'box2') {
     box.parent = [{ id: 'box0' }];
   }
  
   return box;
      
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But this is to add a new value. I also would like to edit existing value and delete a particular value.

Comment: You could already do anything with the filtered box object. Don't rely on SO for everything you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize this JSON string into a javascript object, modify the property in the object and then serializing the javascript object into a JSON string :

```
var json = '[{"box":"box1","parent":[{"id":"box0"}],"child":[{"id":"box2"}]},{"box":"box2","parent":[{"id":"box1"}],"child":[{"id":"box3"},{"id":"box4"}]}]';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
obj[1].parent[0].id = "whatever";
var newjson = JSON.stringify(obj);
```